# ASP.NET MVC - Displaying data in a table inside Jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, grid

I have a webform with a textbox and search button, when the user enters a search term and clicks the search button  want to get the list of users and display in a table and there should be a select button on each row.

```
  <div id="panelStudentResults" class="panel panel-primary" style="display:none">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Student Results</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
               
            </div>

        </div>
       
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('#searchStudent').click(function () {
        var name = $('#Name').val();
        var url = "/StudentAdmin/GetStudents";
        alert(name);
        $.get(url, { SearchTerm: name }, function (data) {
            $("#panelStudentResults").show();
            //$("#rData").html(data);
        });
    })
</script>

        public List<Student> GetStudents(string SearchTerm)
        {
            List<Student> studentsList = new List<Student>();
            studentsList.Add(new Student { Id = 1, Name = "John"});
            studentsList.Add(new Student { Id = 2, Name = "Ricky"});
            studentsList.Add(new Student { Id = 3, Name = "Deo"});
            studentsList.Add(new Student { Id = 4, Name = "Len" });
            return studentsList.Where(student => student.Name.StartsWith(SearchTerm)).ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a PartialView for the table and return it from the Action.
Use $("#panelStudentResults").load in order to append the html that was returned.